# How to Copy files embedded in an Excel Worksheet and pasting it in a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small Macro with a Selection Window where you can check different options. The goal is that when you click "Create PDF". It will create a pdf with all your choices and copy a specific file that changes with your selections (embedded on a worksheet) and paste it to a location with created pdf. How do i do that?

Here is what i have at the moment, but it is only a jpg and not an embedded file:

```vb
Sub Schaltfläche6_Klicken()
UserForm1.Show
MkDir "C:\test\Excel"
'Create and assign variables
Dim saveLocation As String
saveLocation = "C:\Excel\Dummy.pdf"

'Save Active Sheet(s) as PDF
Worksheets("Dummy").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:=saveLocation
End Sub
```

Sincerely Pascal

Googled it but couldnt really find something that works for me

Comment: See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512560/save-embedded-word-doc-as-pdf). Do not look at the solution because that is for MAC. For windows, see the approach that I took in the question itself.

Comment: @SiddharthRout thanks for the response. could you be a bit more precise? I cant really find my solution in your post.

Comment: See the `shp.OLEFormat.Activate` option in the quesiton. That will work in your case